# ¿Cómo serializar JSON en JQUERY?

Tags: jquery, json

Necesito serializar un objeto a `JSON`. estoy usando `JQUERY`, existe algún método estándar para realizar esto ?

Tengo un arreglo definido así:

```
var paises= new Array();
paises[0] = 'COL';
paises[1] = 'VEN';
...
```

Necesito convertir esto en un `String` para pasar a `$.ajax()` así:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Concessions.aspx/GetConcessions",
    data: "{'paises':['COL','VEN']}",
...
```

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo evitar la inyección de SQL en PHP? o ¿Cómo convertir una cadena a JSON en PHP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para convertir un objeto a un string, use `JSON.stringify`:

```
var json_text = JSON.stringify(objeto, null, 2);
```

Para convertir un string de JSON a objeto, use `JSON.parse`:

```
var objeto = JSON.parse(texto_json);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solo sería necesario crear un objeto con propiedad `paises` y asignarle tu Array. Para convertir tu objeto solo utilizarías `JSON.stringify`.

```js
var paises = new Array();
paises[0] = 'COL';
paises[1] = 'VEN';

var objeto = {
  paises: paises
};

var jsonPaises = JSON.stringify(objeto);

console.log(objeto);
```